# Canonical Urls with django wagtail puput

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I made my first blog with puput and wagtail.

I´m using the following tag for canonical_urls:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{% block canonical %}{% canonical_url %}{% endblock canonical %}"/>
```

If I open my website with http, it renders http://www.example.com as canonical.
If I open my website with https, it renders https://www.example.com as canonical.

If I´m not wrong, google will treat http and https as differents pages. Is it possible to set all canonical urls as https only or it doesn´t matter?

Comment: Have you considered configuring your web server to redirect all http requests to https, so that the issue doesn't arise?

Comment: It´s on a docker on divio.I dont think I can change it.

Comment: I just found I can set enverioment variables. I think it´s the best option. Thanks for the attention (again)!